# jQuery .ajax and Same Origin Policy

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I have a working HTML5/JS app that I'm trying to port to the browser for a demo.  The app was built to run in a vehicle and used the vehicle manufacturer's network API for get/post requests.

For the browser version of this, I'm trying to use jQuery for get/post.  However, I'm immediately running into issues.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<API I AM CALLING>. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've looked into the same origin policy, but still do not fully understand it.  I can browse to the URL being used, and see the JSON I'm trying to retrieve.

Looking around the web, a lot of people suggested specifying JSONP as the dataType in my ajax call.  I gave this a shot, with no success.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    log("success getting JSON from " + url);
                    success(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    log("error getting JSON from " + url + ", code " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    log("textStatus is " + textStatus);
                    log("errorThrown is " + errorThrown);
                },
            });
```

An error shows up in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

After that, my error callback is used.

```
error getting JSON from http://<API I AM CALLING>, code {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
textStatus is parsererror
errorThrown is Error: jQuery180006523256213404238_1346098086632 was not called
```

It looks like the server is responding with the JSON data I need.  But, I'm guessing that jQuery is expecting this data to be wrapped in a function so it fails to parse it.

I have no control over the server whose API I am calling.  Since the data is coming back to the browser, I feel like there's got to be some way to access it.

Note:
App is only targeted for webkit browsers, I don't need to support any others.  Leaving dataType as "json" only causes problems in Chrome but Safari seems to work fine due to different security policies.  Looking for a code workaround, not simply launching Chrome with special arguments.  This still happens in Chrome even when I host my code on Apache, so it's not just limited to me trying to open index.html locally.

Comment: You can't simply change from `json` to `jsonp` without updating the API to return valid `jsonp`. `JSON` != `JSONP`

Comment: I realize this, but it does bypass the same origin policy, and the server is able to respond with the JSON I need.  I just need to figure out how to get my hands on that data.

Comment: You can't get your hands on it if it isn't valid `JSONP`. Another option though is to use the `JSON` datatype and have your server return CORS headers.

Comment: Like I said, no control over the server

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Then you have to use a proxy of some sort, such as YQL or a proxy on your own server that gets the data for you, either making it a valid same-domain json request, or a valid cross-domain jsonp request.

Comment: As `Kevin b` said, you can use a proxy, a remote call from your server and then return the data to jQuery.

Comment: I can create an iFrame and set its source to the url I'm trying to call.  This will result in displaying the JSON I need to access.  Any way to just grab the iframe's contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to write a service that proxies the JSON service you want and returns JSONP. I've written many proxy services like this so I can get around the same origin policy.

For instance: http://high-cloud-3702.heroku.com/

This service is a jsonp proxy for urban dictionary.

You can write a proxy like this in Sinatra very easily and host it on Heroku for free.

The key to a proxy like this is this code:

```
get '/' do
  callback = params.delete('callback') # jsonp
  json = <function_to_get_data_here>.to_json

  if callback
    content_type :js
    response = "#{callback}(#{json})" 
  else
    content_type :json
    response = json
  end
  response
end
```

Comment: The OP can just return JSON from his server.

Comment: I guess I assumed the OP was not in control of the server he is calling to when he said "I have no control over the server whose API I am calling". However, if he can host his app on the same domain that the service exists he can just make a regular JSON call...